# How to solve Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'MatMenuPanel<any>' in Angular 14

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, regression

[You can find a minimum reproduction of the error at this stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nwdr32)

```
<mat-toolbar>
   <a [matMenuTriggerFor]="index" mat-button *ngFor="let item of menuItems; let index = index">{{item.label}}</a>
   <mat-menu #index="matMenu">
     <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
     <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
   </mat-menu>
</mat-toolbar>
```

In the code above, in version of Angular greater than 12, [there appears to be a regression in how MatMenu works](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24078).

It results in an error of `Type number is not assignable to type MatMenuPanel | null`

This one bug not only blocks me from finishing my task but basically breaks my approach entirely.

Using the suggested work-around online of adding `"exactOptionalPropertyTypes": false,` to tsconfig.ts has had no effect.

Comment: does temporary solution `[matMenuTriggerFor]="$any(index)"` work?

Comment: @AndrewAllen it DOES solve that problem. You should post as an answer. Of course, now I have a new problem....but probably has more to do with my approach now :)

Comment: It does solve the compilation error but matMenu class is still broken since it expects a MatPanel association.