# ionic 6 ion-datetime restricting dates to just max 2 dates

Tags: javascript, datetime, ionic-framework

I am using ionic 6 for [ion-datetime](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime) with property `multiple="true"`. I want to make sure that user cannot select more than 2 dates. and if user selects the 3rd date then i want to remove the oldest date automatically rather throwing a validation error. The code is like below:

```
  <ion-datetime presentation="date" multiple="true" preferWheel="false" [(ngModel)]="packageEstimatedDated" (ionChange)="validateDates()"></ion-datetime>
```

for .ts

```
packageEstimatedDated
async validateDates(){
    console.log("selected dates length:", this.packageEstimatedDated.length)
    
    if(this.packageEstimatedDated.length === 3){
      console.log("after remove extra date", this.packageEstimatedDated)
      this.packageEstimatedDated.splice(0,1)
      console.log("after removed", this.packageEstimatedDated)
    }
  }
```

The problem is that even the splice is removing the element but it still not really. Here is the output i see when i select 4 dates one by one:

```
selected dates length: 1
new-order.page.ts:61 selected dates length: 2
new-order.page.ts:61 selected dates length: 3
new-order.page.ts:72 after remove extra date (3) ['2022-08-10', '2022-08-18', '2022-08-23']
new-order.page.ts:74 after removed (2) ['2022-08-18', '2022-08-23']
new-order.page.ts:61 selected dates length: 4
```

Comment: your function as tagged as async.....where is the await?

Comment: there is more code after this that the stuff to firebase db. that uses await

Comment: Please post code to show a minimum reproducible example. It will be the best way to get an answer to your question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: what do you think is above posted? it has the minimal needed code to reproduce the issue. did u read my question or just blindly became advocate of so?

Comment: No....minimum reproducible would be a stackblitz that actually demonstrates the issue. As you stated, "there's more code and stuff".  What you have here doesn't show/properly illustrate the issue. Did u read the info at the link or just blindly reply? ;-)

Comment: For example my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73154575/how-to-solve-type-number-is-not-assignable-to-type-matmenupanelany-in-angu or my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73240949/change-cursor-to-pointer-on-ion-input/73243669#73243669